# Changing Stack View dimensions to be a ratio

Tags: swift, stack

I am wondering how I can change the dimensions of a stack view to be a ratio, specifically 7:6. So far, I have constrained the Stack View with "Align Center X to: Superview" and "Height Equals: 400" and "Align Top to: Safe Area Equals: 100." How can I maintain a constant ratio between the width and the height across all devices? Thanks!

For User Interface, I am using Storyboard, not SwiftUI.

[What I have right Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfJBD.png)
I am not exactly sure why this doesn't work, but it is probably my understanding of aspect ratio. My main issue is how to use the (phone width - 20 points) to determine the height so that it is a ratio.

[Expected result, but I don't want to manually set the height and width, rather a ratio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDegd.png)

Comment: Is the aspect ratio constraint what you are looking for? It's just below the place where you add width and height constraints.

Comment: I think it might be, but because I am a beginner, I have no idea how to use it. I tried setting the aspect ratio of my grid to 7:6, but It ended up stretching the whole thing horizontally. 
My idea is to first constrain the stack view horizontally with 10 points on both the left and right, and also center it vertically. Then, using what is left (ie the phone view - the 20 points), define the height to be 6/7 of that. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please show your attempts. Explain how they didn't work, and show the expected result.

Comment: I have added the additional information.

Comment: "My main issue is how to use the (phone width - 20 points) to determine the height" You mean use the phone width - 20 points to determine the ***width***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to manually set the height and width

Then you should remove the "Height Equals: 400" constraint that you currently have! After that the layout should be fixed. It should look like:

[image]

Just for completeness' sake, all the stack views should have distribution=fill equally, and alignment=fill.

The height=400 constraint is causing the constraints to conflict. If height = 400, then width would be about 467 to get an aspect ratio of 7:6, but the width of the super view isn't enough for that. But you also require the leading and trailing of the stack view to be pinned on the leading and trailing of its super view! These constraints can't be simultaneously satisfied.

Note that this layout doesn't look quite nice when in landscape, since the width would be very large and the available height is small. You might want to add variations to install/uninstall constraints based on size classes. In landscape mode, you could pin top and bottom rather than leading and trailing, for example.

Comment: Thank you so much! I made sure of the stack view's distribution and alignment.